# Use XYZ data to create cross sectional profiles across beach terrain, using OS Grid

Tags: database, matlab, geospatial

This might be a slightly long question, but I've recently been doing a bit of R&D on the data processing workflows within the company that I work at and it would be great to see if there are any other ideas on how to speed up a particular script. The Matlab code is:

```
clc
clear
close all

%% Import Inputs

pro_file = readtable('9a10.4_Ynyslas.csv');
matrix_profile = table2array(pro_file(:,2:5));
L = length(matrix_profile(:,1)); %L = number of profile lines

point_file = readtable('Input/Borth/9a10.4/1209ynyslas_ProfilesLW.txt');
matrix_point = table2array(point_file(:,2:3));

%% Pre-settings;

E = matrix_point(:,1); %Easting column
N = matrix_point(:,2); %Northing column
E_num = length(E); %Number of elements within easting column = 95
N_num = length(N); %Number of elements within northing column = E_num = 95

z = table2array(point_file(:,4)); %z height
code = table2array(point_file(:,5)); %code
profile = table2array(pro_file(:,1)); %profile ID vector

%Preallocate
chainage = zeros(L,E_num);
d_matrix = zeros(L,E_num);

%% Process Data

for i = 1:L
    xS = matrix_profile(i,1); %x start (Easting) SX
    xF = matrix_profile(i,3); %x Easting End coordinate EX

    yS = matrix_profile(i,2); %y start (Northing) SY
    yF = matrix_profile(i,4); %y finish (Northing) EY

    m = (yF - yS)/(xF - xS); %slope
    c = yS - m*xS; %y-intercept

    A = -m; %x coefficient
    B = 1; %y coefficient
    C = -c; %constant

    for j = 1:E_num
        xp = E(j); %x coordinate of point
        yp = N(j); %y coordinate of point
        d = (abs(A*xp + B*yp + C))/(sqrt(A^2 + B^2)); %distance between point and line
        S2F = sqrt((xF - xS)^2 + (yF - yS)^2); %distance between start and end point of profile
    
    h = sqrt((xp - xS)^2 + (yp - yS)^2); %distance between start point and point
    chainage(i,j) = sqrt(h^2 - d^2);
    %account for negative chainage
    hS = sqrt((xp - xS)^2 + (yp - yS)^2); %distance between start point and point
    hF = sqrt((xp - xF)^2 + (yp - yF)^2); %distance between end point and point
    theta = acosd((hS^2 + S2F^2 - hF^2)/(2*hS*S2F)); %angle at point
    chainage1 = sqrt(h^2 - d^2);
            if theta > 90
               chainegg(i,j) = -chainage1;
            else
               chainegg(i,j) = chainage1;
            end
            
        if d <= 0.1
            d_matrix(i,j) = d; %matrix of all d values under 10 m     
            row = d_matrix(i,:); %iteration of each row in d_matrix
            locate_row = find(row); %find location of non zero elements in row of d_matrix   
            p_iterate(j,:) = profile(i);
            p{i} = p_iterate(locate_row); %I get it but can't explain it
            p1 = vertcat(p{:}); %concatenate/stack profile ID vectors vertically

            error = find(row>0.1); %find location of coordinates greater than 0.1 m from profile line
            error_coord = matrix_point(error,1:2);
        
            coord2profile{i} = matrix_point(locate_row,1:2); %input x and y coordinate values into matrix based on profile line
        
            real_chain{i} = chainegg(i,locate_row)'; %extract true chainage values from each row of chainage matrix
            real_z{i} = z(locate_row); %extract true elevation values from each row of chainage matrix
            real_code{i} = code(locate_row); %extract true code strings from each row of chainage matrix
            real_code1 = vertcat(real_code{:}); %concatenate/stack codes for each profile vertically
        
            v{i} = [coord2profile{i}, real_z{i}, real_chain{i}]; %combine coordinates with corresponding chainag and elevation
           v1 = vertcat(v{:}); %concatenate v matrix for each profile vertically
        end
    
    end
    
end

v2 = [num2cell(v1), real_code1, p1]; %convert v1 and concatenate with real_code1 vector
T = array2table(v2); %convert matrix array to table
G = findgroups(T(:,6)); %find groups in profile ID column
temp = splitapply(@(varargin) {sortrows(table(varargin{:}),4)}, T, G); %order separated 
groups in terms of chainage
T = vertcat(temp{:}); %updated table with chainage column sorted in ascending order
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'Easting' 'Northing' 'Elevation_OD' 'Chainage' 'FC' 
'Reg_ID'}; %name columns
writetable(T, ['Output/2022_Borth_ProfilesLWAJ_Rev1' ...
    '.xls']) %export output table as excel spreadsheet
```

The code essentially takes geospatial ASCII grid XYZ data from a recent LiDAR UAV survey and creates cross-sectional transects that intersect this data. The start and end points of the transects are given to us via OS Grid, easting and northings coordinates (Good because it essentially makes plotting things mathematically simple.). A reduced example of the profile start and end coordinates file is pasted below:

[image]

*Profile ID - Name of the transect, ESOL - Easting coordinate for start of line, NSOL - Northing coordinate for start of line, EEOL - Easting coordinate for end of line, NEOL - Northing coordinate for end of line.*

These coordinates are then used to create a mathematical line between the points and this can then be used to depict which XYZ points fall within a 0.1m boundary of the transect.

A reduced example of the XYZ data is shown below:

[image]

*Point_ID - Unique point name, Easting - Easting coordinate of XYZ point, Northing - Northing coordinate of XYZ point, FC - Sediment classification of point.*

Essentially there will be numerous XYZ points that fall within 0.1m of a particular line and these need to be assigned to the corresponding line, along with establishing a chainage distance (m). This chainage distance is calculated from the beginning of the line and needs to be assigned to every XYZ point. This chainage distance, in cases, can also be a negative  value.

Here is an example of the final output:

[image]

*Profile - Can be inputted manually, however represents a universal unique ID used by coastal engineers in the area, Reg_ID - Is the assigned transect line for the particular XYZ point.*

I hope that the above makes sense. The code generally works well, however when a large XYZ dataset is being used, it has a tendency to get stuck within a loop and dosen't execute fully. It would be great to get some feedback and to see if there are any obvious flaws within the code itself.

Cheers

Comment: Long questions are great!  We like good explanations of the motivation behind code; it makes reviews much better targeted.  I only wish I knew some Matlab so I could write an answer!

Comment: Indentation is off, and some lines are split in a way that makes syntax errors. I’m guessing these are copy-paste issues. Other than that I don’t see any obvious issues with the code after a cursory look. I don’t have the time to understand the algorithm in sufficient detail to help speed it up, sorry.